# Closing a Frame from a Panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Let me first explain the situation,
I have a class with a JPanel called panelclass.
It's method getPanel() returns the JPanel.

In a JFrame class called frameclass, I create a new object of panelclass, got its panel and added it to the frame pane.

What I am trying to achieve is, when a button in paneclass is clicked, It should close this JFrame ie.frameclass.
I donot know how a panelclass can communicate back to the frameclass to close.
I tried this.dispose() and super.dispose() but was not successful even after extending JFrame

Is there a simpler way?
Please do help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few was to achieve this, but the simplest is probably through the use of [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor%28java.awt.Component%29)

This will return the `Window` that the component was added to or `null` if it has no parent window.  From there you can simply call `Window#dispose` to close the frame.

Comment: @XperiazX Don't sound so shocked ;)

Answer (score 1):

> when a button in paneclass is clicked, It should close this JFrame

See [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/). I prefer using something like the `ExitAction' described there. The reason is that your application will behave just like the user clicked on the close button of the frame which means that if you have any WindowListeners added to the window they will be invoked.